# Enable a Service Fabric Service to send PING to an external host (C#)

Tags: c#, ping, azure-service-fabric, windows-firewall, service-fabric-stateless

I have a method in a Service Fabric Stateless Service (not an API) that sends a PING request to an external host. It works on my Local Service Fabric Cluster, but not on the actual cluster on Azure.

I RDP'd to the cluster and pinged hosts, all of them resulted to "Request timed out".

Anyone tried this before? I'm playing around the cluster's Firewall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ICMP is blocked inside Azure. 
You can use PSPing to check connectivity though.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48334753/enable-a-service-fabric-service-to-send-ping-to-an-external-host-c).

> Because the ICMP protocol is not permitted through the Azure load
>   balancer, you will notice that you are unable to ping an Azure VM from
>   the internet, and from within the Azure VM, you are unable to ping
>   internet locations.