# No internet from within local Service Fabric Mesh Container

Tags: docker, azure-service-fabric, hyper-v, docker-for-windows, azure-service-fabric-mesh

I'm playing around with Service Fabric Mesh on my local PC, but I'm struggling with internet access from within a (Windows) Container.

I'm using the standard web app template from Visual Studio 2017:

```
public static async Task<int> Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var test = await (new System.Net.Http.HttpClient()).GetStringAsync("http://google.com");
            Console.WriteLine(test);
```

You would expect some HTML to be printed out but I get this exception:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such host is known ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known
>      at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetStringAsyncCore(Task`1 getTask)
>      at Web1.Program.Main(String[] args)

The base docker image used is `microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1709` and if I run:
`docker run microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1709 ping google.com`
then I get:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker run microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1709 ping google.com

Pinging google.com [172.217.168.238] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.217.168.238: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.168.238: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.168.238: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=56
Reply from 172.217.168.238: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=56

Ping statistics for 172.217.168.238:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 15ms, Maximum = 16ms, Average = 15ms
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Update 1:

When I run the Docker image directly I get:

```
PS C:\Users\XXX> docker run microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1803 ipconfig.exe /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : XXX
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : XXX

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : XXX
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-38-EE-09
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1c14:1ec3:9b85:5f56%4(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.192.4(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.192.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 67114333
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-23-7C-13-F1-00-15-5D-38-EE-09
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.192.1
                                       10.10.0.184 <-- IP of my local machine
                                       10.10.0.1 <-- My router
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

If I do the same (`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("ipconfig.exe", "/all");`) inside the code running in Service Fabric:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : 0ded1f75fa51
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : Application1

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : XXX
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-15-5D-38-E5-2C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1d25:4204:2cd4:1bb0%4(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.202.176(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.192.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 67114333
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-23-7C-11-32-00-15-5D-38-E5-2C
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.192.1
                                       10.10.0.184
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

As you can see 10.10.0.1 (my router/gateway is missing as a DNS Server in the last dump). How do I add that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add EXPOSE command to the beginning of dockerfile, it's a known bug, i.e.

`FROM ..
WORKDIR ...
EXPOSE 80`

Answer (score 0):

Also there was a DNS issue in Windows Containers 1709. Can you try using a more recent base layer and try again?

Also, ICMP is blocked inside Azure. 
You can use PSPing to check connectivity though.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48334753/enable-a-service-fabric-service-to-send-ping-to-an-external-host-c).

> Because the ICMP protocol is not permitted through the Azure load
>   balancer, you will notice that you are unable to ping an Azure VM from
>   the internet, and from within the Azure VM, you are unable to ping
>   internet locations.

Comment: I've just tried with `microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1803` with no luck. Ping works when running in docker, but not inside the cluster :(