# Unable to ping service fabric cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I recently created a new azure service fabric cluster resource.  I've been trying to ping it, but I consistently get a timeout error.  I haven't deployed any of my microservices yet so I'm not trying to hit any of those directly.  I'm trying to figure out if there is some sort of additional setup.

```
ping myapp-dev.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com

Pinging myapp-dev.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com [00.000.000.00] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 00.000.000.00:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable a Service Fabric Service to send PING to an external host (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48334753/enable-a-service-fabric-service-to-send-ping-to-an-external-host-c)

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in your local PowerShell. If everything is properly confdigured, you will see some information otherwise some error. Let us know the error in that case.

```shell
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint {yourClusterName}.azure.com:19000 -X509Credential -FindType FindByThumbprint -StoreLocation CurrentUser -StoreName My -FindValue {YourCertificateThumbprintHere} -ServerCertThumbprint {YourCertificateThumbprintHere}
```

Certificate thumbprint will be a 40-characters long hexadecimal string, something like `439CE48DE7E123DA97FD2F11C039A583FF53000B`.